# Conditional MAX function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I'm using array formula to return MAX value from column (Count) based on column (client Name). Each client has multiple account numbers repeated multiple times. I intend to return the count of account number which is present in the column (Acct #) maximum times for a client.

I'm able to get the satisfactory results ***except*** when two or more account numbers for the same client have same count as then I want to return `NULL` or BLANK but not the MAX count.

**Below is an example:**
Acct # 4565 & 7898 is repeated 6 time for XYZ LTD. Since, for XYZ LTD. the maximum time the acct # is repeated is 6 but more than one account is repeated 6 times, I want to return `NULL` or BLANK in Column (Count MAX)

**Table with Array Formulas:**

```
Client Name Acct #   Count                       Count Max
XYZ LTD.    1234    =COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,A:A,A2)    =MAX(IF(A:A=A2,C:C))
XYZ LTD.    4565    =COUNTIFS(B:B,B3,A:A,A3)    =MAX(IF(A:A=A3,C:C))
XYZ LTD.    4565    =COUNTIFS(B:B,B4,A:A,A4)    =MAX(IF(A:A=A4,C:C))
XYZ LTD.    4565    =COUNTIFS(B:B,B5,A:A,A5)    =MAX(IF(A:A=A5,C:C))
XYZ LTD.    4565    =COUNTIFS(B:B,B6,A:A,A6)    =MAX(IF(A:A=A6,C:C))
XYZ LTD.    1234    =COUNTIFS(B:B,B7,A:A,A7)    =MAX(IF(A:A=A7,C:C))
XYZ LTD.    1234    =COUNTIFS(B:B,B8,A:A,A8)    =MAX(IF(A:A=A8,C:C))
XYZ LTD.    4565    =COUNTIFS(B:B,B9,A:A,A9)    =MAX(IF(A:A=A9,C:C))
XYZ LTD.    1234    =COUNTIFS(B:B,B10,A:A,A10)  =MAX(IF(A:A=A10,C:C))
XYZ LTD.    4565    =COUNTIFS(B:B,B11,A:A,A11)  =MAX(IF(A:A=A11,C:C))
XYZ LTD.    7898    =COUNTIFS(B:B,B12,A:A,A12)  =MAX(IF(A:A=A12,C:C))
XYZ LTD.    7898    =COUNTIFS(B:B,B13,A:A,A13)  =MAX(IF(A:A=A13,C:C))
XYZ LTD.    7898    =COUNTIFS(B:B,B14,A:A,A14)  =MAX(IF(A:A=A14,C:C))
XYZ LTD.    7898    =COUNTIFS(B:B,B15,A:A,A15)  =MAX(IF(A:A=A15,C:C))
XYZ LTD.    7898    =COUNTIFS(B:B,B16,A:A,A16)  =MAX(IF(A:A=A16,C:C))
XYZ LTD.    7898    =COUNTIFS(B:B,B17,A:A,A17)  =MAX(IF(A:A=A17,C:C))
```

Table With Results:

```
Clien Name  Acct #  Count   Count Max
XYZ LTD.    1234    4       6
XYZ LTD.    4565    6       6
XYZ LTD.    4565    6       6
XYZ LTD.    4565    6       6
XYZ LTD.    4565    6       6
XYZ LTD.    1234    4       6
XYZ LTD.    1234    4       6
XYZ LTD.    4565    6       6
XYZ LTD.    1234    4       6
XYZ LTD.    4565    6       6
XYZ LTD.    7898    6       6
XYZ LTD.    7898    6       6
XYZ LTD.    7898    6       6
XYZ LTD.    7898    6       6
XYZ LTD.    7898    6       6
XYZ LTD.    7898    6       6
```

In this example, the **expected result** in column(Count Max) is blank value.

Or Can this be using VBA?

Comment: I know this is not what you asked for, but would you rather generate a list of unique name AND account # and the count for each unique combination?

Comment: No, there's a reason to pull the max count. I've just put the 1st half of the process. The max value is used to replace with a particular number for the clients but not when Max count has more than one number.

Answer (score 0):

take your formula that is working for you and place it in this formula replacing YOUR FORMULA

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,$A2,$B$2:$B2,$B2)>1,"",YOUR FORMULA)
```

Copy down as far as you need.  it will display "" when the account name and # are repeated and the value of your formula when its the first instance.

[image: proof of concept]

The formula you are using is an array formula so you have to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, not just <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when you finish.  When done properly it will add {} around the formula which cannot be added manually.  This will be a single cell array formula.  Once you have done this for the first cell, copy the cell down as required.

Comment: This isn't working. It's still returning the max count even if the max value is repeated for more than one account # under same client.